# Internet monitoring through service in Android

Tags: android

I want to monitor internet in every page in my project through service. I don't have any code regarding this. I have method how to check internet connection, but I want to implement it through service.

1. Is it possible ? if yes please provide me some methods or logic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to check INTERNET Connectivity in every  of your activity, Here is code for it.

```
public abstract class NetworkUtils {

    public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

For this you need to require following permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Then you can check INTERNET Connectivity in any activity by following code,

```
if (!NetworkUtils.isNetworkConnected(getApplicationContext())) 
{
   // Internet is present
}
else
{
    // Error msg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also implement like below:

```
public boolean isInternetConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    boolean ret = true;
    if (conMgr != null) {
        NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (i != null) {
            if (!i.isConnected()) {
                ret = false;
            }

            if (!i.isAvailable()) {
                ret = false;
            }
        }

        if (i == null)
            ret = false;
    } else
        ret = false;
    return ret;
}
```

and check like below in your service or AsynTask:

```
if(isInternetConnected()){
 //add your logic
 }else{
 //add your logic
 }
```

**Note:** add required internet `permission` into your `manifest.xml` file